# Problem with finding the intersection point between a line and triangle

Tags: geometry, matrices

I have a mathematical problem that I'm trying to solve, but the equations I have derived don't give the correct output when utilised on concrete problems. However, I can't figure out what the problem is.

## Problem specification and preparatory math

I want to take a line and a triangle, both in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and see if the line passes through the triangle at some point. That is, I have a triangle with vertices $v_0$, $v_1$, and $v_2$ and a line with a starting point, $s$, and a point, $d$, that specifies the direction of the line.

I can then specify any point on the line using the equation

\begin{equation}
s+td
\end{equation}

where $t$ is a real number, and I can specify any point on the triangle using the equation

\begin{equation}
v_0+ue_1+ve_2
\end{equation}

where $u$ and $v$ are real numbers such that $0<u$, $0<v$, and $u+v<1$, and where

\begin{equation}
e_1 = v_1-v_0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e_2 = v_2-v_0
\end{equation}

Now, if there is a point that lies both on the line as well as on the triangle, there should be a solution to the following equation

\begin{equation}
v_0+ue_1+ve_2 = s+td
\end{equation}

where $u$, $v$, and $t$ together specifies this point. We can then reformulate the equation above to

\begin{equation}
-td+ue_1+ve_2 = s-v_0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
(\begin{matrix}-d & e_1 & e_2\end{matrix})(\begin{matrix}t & u & v\end{matrix})^T = s–v_0
\end{equation}

We can then make the following definitions

\begin{equation}
A=(\begin{matrix}-d & e1 & e2\end{matrix})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x = (\begin{matrix}t & u & v\end{matrix})^T
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
b = s-v_0
\end{equation}

which gives us the equation

\begin{equation}
Ax = b
\end{equation}

which in turn can be reformulated to

\begin{equation}
A^{-1}Ax=A^{-1}b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x=A^{-1}b
\end{equation}

So, to get $t$, $u$, and $v$, which we need to specify the point where the line and the triangle intersect, we should simply solve $A^{-1}b$. Seems legit to me.

## Concrete examples that turn out wrong

However, this equation doesn't seem to be correct when I try it out on real problems.

Let's take a line where $s=(1,1,1)$ and $d=(1,1,2)$, and a triangle where $v_0=(0,0,3)$, $v_1=(4,0,3)$, and $v_2=(2,4,3)$. The line should intersect this triangle at $p=(1,1,3)$. Let's see if that's the answer we get by using the equation above as well.

First, we get

\begin{equation}
e_1 = (4,0,0)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
e_2 = (2,4,0)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
b = (1,1,-2)
\end{equation}

When plugging these numbers into $x = A^{-1}b$ we get

\begin{equation}
x = (1,0.25,0.5)
\end{equation}

Applying this back to the equation for the triangle, $v_0 + ue_1 + ve_2$, we get

\begin{equation}
(0,0,3)+0.25(4,0,0)+0.5(2,4,0)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
(0,0,3)+(1,0,0)+(1,2,0) = (2,2,3)
\end{equation}

which clearly isn't $(1,1,3)$ as predicted. Further, applying it to the equation for the line, $s+td$, we get

\begin{equation}
(1,1,1)+1(1,1,2)=(2,2,3)
\end{equation}

which isn't $(1,1,3)$ as predicted.

This is just one out of many examples where I don't get the expected output. For example, sometimes, I can't inverse $A$ at all.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken but $s+td\neq p$ for every $t\in \mathbb{R}$ in your example, i.e. your point does not on the line.

Comment: Also $b-v_0=(1,1,-2)$ in your example, not $(1,1,2)$.

Comment: No, that's right; $s+td = p$ only for one specific $t$ (in that case, $t = 2$. But how is this a problem you mean?

Comment: $(1,1,1)+2(1,1,2)=(3,3,5)$ is it not?

Comment: Yes, $b=(1,1,-2)$. That was a typo. Thanks!

And yes, $(1,1,1)+2(1,1,2) = (3,3,5)$ but where do you get $2$ from?

Comment: You said $t=2$ gives the point $p$. Don't you mean $d=(0,0,2)$?

Comment: Sorry, I'm obviously confused. You're right again. Come to think of it, it doesn't seem possible to satisfy the equation $(1,1,1)+x(1,1,2) = (1,1,3)$. WTF? :/ I'm obviously *seriously* confused here.

Comment: The solution $(2,2,3)$ is correct, the mathematical explanation in the first part as well.

Comment: DAMN! Yeah, I see it now. I have thought of $d$ as an absolute position when it really is a vector.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that I thought of $d$ as an absolute position when it really was a vector, specifying a direction. That's why I thought that the intersection should appear at $(1,1,3)$ when it, in reality, should appear at $(2,2,3)$, which also was the answer I got from my equation.